# drools code for score calculation logic

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I want to schedule events using optaplanner in which required resource by event is a soft constraint.

I have done score calculation in java code like :

```
int resources = 0;
int quantity = 0;
for(ResourceAvailability availability : eventDate.getResourceAvailabilities()){
    for(ResourceAvailability required : event.getResourceAvailabilities()){
         if(availability.equals(required)){
              resources += required.getQuantity();
              quantity += availability.getQuantity();
         }
    }
}
// Soft constraints
int resourcesAvailable = quantity - resources;
if (resourcesAvailable < 0) {
    softScore += resourcesAvailable;
}
```

This is working but it is slow,i want to get equivalent drools code for this soft score calculation logic.

So how to write drools code for this??

I checked drools file of machine reassignment problem,but could not relate it with my problem.

Here Event is my planning entity and EventDate is planning variable.

I am writing drools rule like :

```
rule "requiredResources"
    when
        $eventDate : EventDate()
        $requiredResources : Number(intValue > 1) from accumulate(
            Event(
                eventDate == $eventDate,
                //here logic for comparing required and available resource and then find
                //sum of required resources and available resoulces
                //add difference to score
            ),
            sum($quantity)
        )
    then
        System.out.println($requiredResources+$availableResources);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the machine reassignment example](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/machinereassignment/solver/machineReassignmentScoreRules.drl#L40):

```
rule "machineUsage"
  when
    $machineCapacity : MrMachineCapacity($machine : machine, $resource : resource)
    accumulate(
        $processAssignment : MrProcessAssignment(machine == $machine),
        $usageTotal : sum($processAssignment.getUsage($resource))
    )
  then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch($capacity - $usage); // see docs chapter score calculation
end
```

Comment: Please take another, close look at the Machine Reassignment example and the Drools rule engine reference manual's chapter about the rule language (and the score calculation chapter in the OptaPlanner reference manual).